# How can I solve this window builder issue in eclipse?

Tags: java, windowbuilder

I have installed window builder on my eclipse and when I tried to use the design tab, the window is not showing properly and I cannot use any of the features present in the palette window. And you can see it from the photo that the minimize,maximize,close is missing in the window.

[issue photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2S0e.png)

Comment: What Eclipse version are you using? What Java version are you using? What platform are you on?

Comment: @Abra Java version is 8 but for eclipse I don't know which version but it's released date is 2022/09, Windows 11

Comment: @Abra can u please help me resolve this

Comment: No, I can't. Try  the _WindowBuilder_ [forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=214)